# dbt core can not connect to bigquery due to permission issue (roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator)

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

Im trying to set up dbt core on my local machine and build the db connection to bigquery but it is throwing an error while trying to parse the service account key file.
-dbt debug command returns a Connection test: [ERROR] without any additional details
-if I try to run dbt run --select for any models I get a permission error although I have granted Service Account Create Token role to the bigquery service account. (the error: Unable to generate access token, if you're using impersonate_service_account, make sure your initial account has the "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator" role on the account you are trying to impersonate.)
Most probably, Im doing something wrong with granting permissions but I have no clue what it is
Does anyone face this before and might know what is causing the incident here?
[profiles.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leDtf.png)
[what dbt debug returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUwlW.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you try: gcloud auth application-default login
Here is the doc for this command: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login